# Suppress single instance of the warning: possible loss of data - caused by truncation through casting

Tags: c++

**Circumstance**

So I know there are plenty of questions addressing this already [(e.g.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717022/conversion-from-xxxx-to-yyyy-possible-loss-of-data-suppression), but I thought mine was rather specific so I would ask it anyway. I have converted the original *ping.c* code to work with a program running on `RTEMS`, an embedded operating system (not really important to the story, but interesting). In the original code there is a check sum generator, and at the end is the following line:

```
answer = ~sum;              // truncate to 16 bits
```

where:

```
OSINT sum;
u_short answer;
```

So this truncation is the desired behavior, but it is obviously going to throw this warning:

```
Warning 30  warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'OSINT' to 'u_short', possible loss of data
```

---

**Question**

Is it possible to suppress this warning? Since the desired behavior is truncation, it seems like this wont be possible?

Otherwise, is there a way to address this, can i cast this in a certain way (`static_Cast<` and the like) that will stop this warning and still staisfy the need to do this operation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable warning in MSVC++2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440614/disable-warning-in-msvc2010)

Comment: @xaxxon I dont think this is a dupe, i am not including a header file and the OS and answers dont match the problem i had.

Comment: Regardless, that link has the actual answer to the question in the title.

Comment: @xaxxon Now it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `~` causes a promotion of the data type to `int`. (This is C++ standard.) Now you have 32 bits. And you want to assign them to the 16 bit variable `answer`. That's why the warning.

You can avoid the warning by explicitly casting to a 16 bit type after the bitwise operator, i.e.:

```
answer = (u_short)~sum;
```

or a bit more explicit:

```
answer = static_cast<u_short>(~sum);
```

Comment: Wow, how did this question escape me for like 4 years. I absolutely know the answer now. Thanks for finding this.